# show that if $f$ is non constant and entire , $e^f$ is transcendental

Tags: complex-analysis

Entire function that is not a polynomial is called an entire transcendental function.

I know that $\infty$ is an essential singularity of $f$ iff $f$ entire transcendental function. Hence, I only need to show that $e^f$ has an essential singularity at $\infty$. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler: $e^f$ is zero-free, so by the fundamental theorem of algebra $e^f$ can't be a non-constant polynomial. (For a complete solution you should also show that $e^f$ is constant implies that $f$ is constant.)

Comment: doesn't the first statement already prove the claim?